# Value in useSelector return before dispatch

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

thanks for reading.

I have a problem that comes down to:

```
function PrivateRoutes ({component:Component, ...rest}){

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [headers, setHeaders] = useState({
    headers:{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'authorization': localStorage.getItem('sback_id')
    }
  })
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(boolUserVerify(headers));
  } ,[dispatch, headers])

  const {isAuthenticated} = useSelector(state => state.authe);

  return (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => (
      isAuthenticated ? (<Component {...props}/>) : (<Redirect to={{pathname:'/register', state:{from:props.location}}}/>)
    )} />
  )

}
```

every time I render the component for the first time it takes the initial value with the useSelector before the dispatch is performed.

When i execute dispatch in useEffect this isAuthenticated value is true, but in the first render component return false.

I need return isAuthenticated true when dispatch execute.

Example

1. dispatch(boolUserVerify(headers))
2. pick new value
       --after--
3. Render private route

RouterPrivate

Answer (score 0):

`useSelector` returns a value selected from the store.

`useEffect` runs after the component is rendered: you already took some value using `useSelector`

Answer (score 0):

Hooks aren't evaluated based on a condition but as an when they come in the execution order. Also the `useEffect` is run after the initial render so by that time the `useSelector` has already executed.

You need to add a loading state in your reducer. The initial value of `isLoading in reducer will be true`. When you dispatch an action and the state is update you set the state `isLoading to false` and post that you evaluate your isAuthenticated value.

However you must not dispatch the boolUserVerify in PrivateRoute but in the parent component where the PrivateRoutes are rendered. Ideally this would be your top level component

```
function App () {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [headers, setHeaders] = useState({
    headers:{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'authorization': localStorage.getItem('sback_id')
    }
  });

  useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(boolUserVerify(headers));
   } ,[dispatch, headers])

   const {isAuthenticated, isLoading} = useSelector(state => state.authe);
   if(isLoading) {
          return <Loader />; 
   }
   return <PrivateRoute path="/path" component={Component} />
}

function PrivateRoutes ({component:Component, ...rest}){

  const {isAuthenticated} = useSelector(state => state.authe);

  return (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => (
      isAuthenticated ? (<Component {...props}/>) : (<Redirect to={{pathname:'/register', state:{from:props.location}}}/>)
    )} />
  )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try add  to reducer loading value

```
state = {loading: true, isAuth: false, wrongAuth: false}
switch(state, action){
  case SUCCESS_AUTH:
    return{
      loading: false,
       auth: true
    }
  case FAILED_AUTH:
    return{
      loading: false,
       auth: false,
       wrongAuth: true
    }
  default:
    return state
  }
```